# Добавление в список Python

Tags: python, list, append

Как добавить в список по очереди первую букву из первого инпута, затем первую букву со второго инпута, вторую букву из первого инпута и вторую букву со второго инпута и т.д.?

Код ниже просто добавляет первые буквы первого, потом буквы второго:

```
word_1 = input("First word: ")
word_2 = input("Second word: ")
a = []
for word in word_1:
    a.append(word)
for word2 in word_2:
    a.append(word2)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [57]: from itertools import chain, zip_longest

In [58]: list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest('ABCD', 'XYZ')))
Out[58]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'Y', 'C', 'Z', 'D', None]
```

Без использования модулей:

```
In [76]: w1
Out[76]: 'ABCD'

In [77]: w2
Out[77]: 'XYZ'

In [78]: a = []
    ...: for i in range(max(len(w1), len(w2))):
    ...:     if i < len(w1):
    ...:         a.append(w1[i])
    ...:     if i < len(w2):
    ...:         a.append(w2[i])
    ...:

In [79]: a
Out[79]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'Y', 'C', 'Z', 'D']
```

Comment: Возможно ли решить задачу более простым способом? имею ввиду бещ использования модулей

Comment: @ValekPotapov, itertools - это не внешний модуль, а часть стандартной библиотеки.